# Using pyLDAvis with custom model

Tags: python, nlp, data-visualization, lda

I have a trained custom LDA model (Hebrew language) and I want to use pyLDAvis in order to visualize it.

I'm referring to the docs and the following resources:

- https://pyldavis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/API.html#pyLDAvis.prepare
- https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/bmabey/pyLDAvis/blob/master/notebooks/pyLDAvis_overview.ipynb
- http://jeriwieringa.com/2018/07/17/pyLDAviz-and-Mallet/

But I still don't understand how does the input for the prepare method looks like.

```
topic_term_dists:array-like, shape (n_topics, n_terms)
Matrix of topic-term probabilities. Where n_terms is len(vocab).

doc_topic_dists :array-like, shape (n_docs, n_topics)
Matrix of document-topic probabilities.

doc_lengths :array-like, shape n_docs
The length of each document, i.e. the number of words in each document. The order of the numbers should be consistent with the ordering of the docs in doc_topic_dists.

vocab :array-like, shape n_terms
List of all the words in the corpus used to train the model.

term_frequency :array-like, shape n_terms
The count of each particular term over the entire corpus. The ordering of these counts should correspond with vocab and topic_term_dists.
```

Does someone have an example for those inputs? Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "custom" LDA model? Did you code it from scratch or are you using a package such as _scikit-learn_ or _gensim_? Then you can use package-specific `prepare` statements that might help you (I do not actually fully understand the documentation above either).

Comment: Code it from scratch. I'm looking for a simple example of low level "input parameters" for the pyLDAvis. Not using any library like gensim or scikit-learn. Thanks